# CSS: Content Overlapping with Sidebar (Tumblr Theme)

Tags: css, tumblr, overlap, overlapping

I grabbed a Tumblr theme and modified it. Now my problem is that the content is overlapping in the sidebar (left). I hope you could help with this one. Thanks in advance! ^_^

For the code I used, please [click here](http://laboumph.tumblr.com/) to be directed on my Tumblr. Right click and select "view page source".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#side` element width is small, increase it to 220.

```
#side {
width: 220px;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Also, your content element has a margin of -10 change it to px.

```
#contents {
width: 400px;
float: left;
margin-left: -10;
}
```

to

```
#contents {
width: 400px;
float: left;
margin-left:-10px;
}
```